# Delete duplicate data and keep the latest record using Oracle SQL not working

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, sql-delete

I have `VK_MODIFY` table where i want to delete all the duplicate data by combination of `ORDERID` and `EXTORID` and keep only the one which has latest `SYSTEM_INSERTED_AT`.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have tried below query but its not working correctly:

```
DELETE FROM VK_MODIFY a
WHERE rowid not in
(SELECT min(rowid)
FROM VK_MODIFY b
where a.ORDERID = b.ORDERID and a.EXTORID = b.EXTORID);
```

Comment: Not working correctly how? It errors or deletes the wrong rows?

Comment: it actually deletes the wrong rows...for example in the example i want to check every same combination of ORDERID and EXTORDID and take the latest system_inserted_at date and delete the other rows...for example here it should keep ORDERID = 197179, EXTORDID = 9821732, SYSTEM_inserted_at = '2019-10-18 18.01.59' and delete other rows for ORDERID = 197179, EXTORDID = 9821732

Comment: How the orderid getting generated? if this is from sequence then it will a easy query that i can post.  If the orderid of newer record will be greater then the old one then we don't need to order based on system_inserted_at

Comment: no there is no sequence for orderid ...its generating random from gui in this table

Comment: ok I have posted the answer which can solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another example which can solve your problem.

```
 DELETE FROM VK_MODIFY WHERE ROWID IN(SELECT TEMP.ROWID FROM(
SELECT ROWID,ORDERID, EXTORID, SYSTEM_INSERTED_AT,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY ORDERID,EXTORID ORDER BY SYSTEM_INSERTED_AT DESC) RN  FROM VK_MODIFY
)TEMP
WHERE TEMP.RN <> 1)
```

Best practice is you should have a primary key field in your table, if you have you can use this field instead of rowid.

Comment: what if for example the SYSTEM_INSERTED_AT has same rows with date and time as given in the example you can see dupliacte rows with SYSTEM_INSERTED_AT has 2020-06-18 09:29:28...Will this work ?

Comment: What you want to do in that case, either delete both or put some other checks by using other columns you have in your table.

Comment: You can try this example seems it will cover that also

Comment: in this case it should keep only one row and delete others which has same SYSTEM_INSERTED_AT

Comment: Yes it will work for this case, only if you have more than 2 duplicates than you will need to run this query multiple times

Comment: its not working sorry ..its deleting incorrect rows

Comment: Do you have any sequential primary key in this table?

Comment: no i dont have sequence or primary key in this table

Comment: now its taking the exact correct number of rows to delete but the only problem is its not keeping the latest SYSTEM_INSERTED_AT row

Comment: Updated, Order by DESC is only required

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM VK_MODIFY a
WHERE SYSTEM_INSERTED_AT not in
(SELECT max(SYSTEM_INSERTED_AT)
FROM VK_MODIFY b
where a.ORDERID = b.ORDERID and a.EXTORID = b.EXTORID);
```

Depending on your schema (indexes, ....), there may be faster solutions.

Comment: what if for example the SYSTEM_INSERTED_AT has same rows with date and time as given in the example you can see dupliacte rows with  SYSTEM_INSERTED_AT has 2020-06-18 09:29:28...Will this work ?

Comment: If there are multiple rows with the same orderid, extorid and system_inserted_at, how do you decide which one to keep?

Comment: there is field FILENAME in this table which must be different in this case..but this activity has to be done only once

Comment: then just add a condition on the filename, as you did not specify which one to choose.

Comment: actually i dont want to add FILENAME condition thats why i didnt specified because FILENAME is not important here so we can remove them ...most important is the combination of ORDERID and EXTORID and to keep only one row for such combination with the latest SYSTEM_INSERTED_AT...

Comment: can we also do order by desc for FILENAME here just to consider only the latest file as we have duplicate SYSTEM_INSERTED_AT ?